# bash_completion rule for resolving ip into hostnames

Tags: bash, ip

I am trying to create a `bash_completion` rule for my script `rmpxe`. This script takes `<hostname>` as its only argument.  It then resolves this hostname into `<ip_address>` and removes the corresponding symlink `/srv/tftp/pxelinux.cfg/<ip_address>`.

The ip address `<ip_address>` in the symlink `/srv/tftp/pxelinux.cfg/<ip_address>` is in hex format, but I have written a simple program in C (`getnameinfo`) which resolves this hex ip address into hostname.

Thus, I can use my program `getnameinfo` to get hostname from hex ip:

```
$ getnameinfo 0A6F010B
server1.mydomain.com
```

So for example, following command would delete the symlink `/srv/tftp/pxelinux.cfg/0A6F010B`

```
 $ rmpxe server1.mydomain.com
```

Now to my `bash_completion` problem:
I have created following code which works fine, except that instead of completing hostnames (as my script expects) it completes hex IP addresses (i.e. the symlink files in my directory `/srv/tftp/pxelinux.cfg/`). I need to somehow integrate into this code, that before the argument is autocompleted, it will be first resolved into hostname.

```
_rmpxe()
{
    local word
    COMPREPLY=()

    if [ 1 -eq "$COMP_CWORD" ]; then
      pushd /srv/tftp/pxelinux.cfg &>/dev/null || return 1
      word="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
      COMPREPLY=($(compgen -f "$word"))
      popd &>/dev/null
    fi

}
complete -F _rmpxe rmpxe
```

In other words, at the moment my bash completion works like this:

```
$ ls /srv/tftp/pxelinux.cfg
0A6F010B 0A6F010C 0A6F010D 0A6F010E

$ rmpxe <tab>
0A6F010B 0A6F010C 0A6F010D 0A6F010E
```

whereas, I need it to work like this:

```
$ rmpxe <tab>
server1.mydomain.com server2.mydomain.com server3.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you used `compgen -f`, meaning `compgen` will list all files and directories under current path. In your case, it means `0A6F010B 0A6F010C 0A6F010D 0A6F010E`.

To get hostnames, you can loop through your current path, feed each IP to `getnameinfo` to get the hostname corresponding to that IP, save it to an array, then use this array as a wordlist with `compgen -W`.

I did a simple test in my environment. I created a file `/etc/bash_completion.d/cuonglm`:

```
_rmpxe() {
  local word
  COMPREPLY=()

  if [ 1 -eq "$COMP_CWORD" ]; then
    pushd /home/cuonglm/test &>/dev/null || return 1
    word="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    HOST_ARR=()
    for i in *; do
      HOST_ARR+=($(/home/cuonglm/getnameinfo "$i"))
    done
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$(printf "%s " "${HOST_ARR[@]}")" -- "$word"))
    popd &>/dev/null
  fi
}
complete -F _rmpxe cuonglm
```

I used your complete function with a little modification:

- I use an array `HOST_ARR` to save hostnames.
- Loop through the current directory (thanks `pushd` before), feeding each filename to `getnameinfo` program.
- Then I use `compgen -W` to make compgen create a wordlist for completion.

And here is the result:

```
$ cuonglm <Tab>
$ cuonglm server<Tab>
server1.example.com  server2.example.com
```

Because two hostnames have the same portion `server`, bash will autocomplete this portion first. If there is another hostname, `Server.example`:

```
$ cuonglm <Tab>
Server.example server1.example.com  server2.example.com
```